# How to track whats causing DTC to keep closing the connection during a job execution?

Tags: sql-server-2014

We have a job with a few steps, and the last step is failing daily.
The step is a bunch of begin transaction, inserts and etc across a linked server.

I'm failing to track "what" is actually causing it to close the connection. the job runs for some fixed ammount of hours and the job step fails every day close to the same running time ( 1.15h ).

how can I track if that's a timeout or anything related to network? I just can't think about it. when looking at past sessions on monitoring tools, the query just, dies.

Hard to give more insight since this is pretty straightforward and there's not much going on.

Answer (score 0):

Verify the [remote query timeout property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/configure-the-remote-query-timeout-server-configuration-option?view=sql-server-ver16) settings under your local server's properties. It likely is set to 1.15 hours (in units of seconds).

[image: Remote Query Settings]

There's a video on how to configure it and further information [here](https://manage.accuwebhosting.com/knowledgebase/2878/How-to-Increase-the-MS-SQL-Remote-Query-Timeout.html).

Comment: yes one of the first things i checked ( forgot to add in the question sorry ). it's the usual 600 do I discarded it since the step runs for +1hr before I see the error log that DTC closed the connection.

Comment: @RacerSQL That's interesting, but that's pretty much the only place to manage it. I might've misspoke though. Please check your remote server's properties too. I forget which side needs to be configured. I would honestly set both to 0 (for no timeout) as a test to see if the issue goes away. Then go from there.